# How to test feeding a PDF to a lambda function

Tags: python, aws-lambda, pypdf

I have written a lambda function who's goal is to accept a pdf, parse it using PyPDF2, and return specific text fields as a payload.

```py
import PyPDF2 as pypdf
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    file_path = event['body']
    pdfdoc=open(file_path,'rb')
    pdfreader=pypdf.PdfFileReader(pdfdoc)
    #dictionary of extracted text fields
    dic = pdfreader.getFormTextFields()
    
    #fields we want to send in our payload
    firstname = dic['name'].split(' ')[0]
    lastname = dic['name[0]'].split(' ')[1]
    
    
    payload = {"FirstName": firstname,
               "LastName": lastname,
              }
    
    return jsonify(payload)
```

The problem is, I dont know if this is going to work and I want to test it by feeding it a pdf and see what error it spits out at me. How can I manually feed my function a PDF without tying it to API Gateway or another app? Ive tested the code locally, but I've never passed a PDF to a lambda function before so this is the part that is throwing me off.

Comment: Why don't you write most of the code locally and then wrap it in the Lambda code?  Except for `file_path` above the rest shouldn't care where it is run.

Comment: @stdunbar I've written all of this code locally and it works, but I've never passed a PDF to a lambda function so I want to make sure it works.